# Date created field displays erratically in views and webform Drupal7 integration

Tags: dates

The native date created field for contacts shows up erratically in my views, some items it works, and some it doesn't.

The modified date field always displays however.

Additionally, there used to be a change log field on the bottom on contact creation, but now it's gone...!

Seems that some items that were created a while back show up, but some I did today don't, and I have no idea why some from a while back show and others don't!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what entity you'd like to add this custom field to - but you refer to "every new contact", so I assume you want it for contacts.

"Date created" and "date modified" already exist as core fields on many entities, including Contact entities.  See screenshots below.  "Modified Date" on contact is on the Change Log tab.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a manual input field, just something on automatic like on Wordpress, when you add a contact, it appends the date you added it, automatically, on top, not at the bottom?

Comment: The first screenshot shows the automatically added creation date.  The second screenshot is just the search interface.  As for putting this at the top, consider using the Contact Summary Editor extension?

Comment: Where can I find this "Contact Summary Editor extension" I found this one: https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.contactlayout. But it doesn't work. I can't find this path:

"Once installed, navigate to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Contact Summary Layouts to open the editor." 

what is the URL about the extension you are mentioning?

Comment: @BrunoVincent that's the correct extension!  I'm sorry it's not working for you.  Have you installed the dependencies?

Comment: Yep, installed everything, I'll keep digging!

Comment: I'm using view and webform now, but still can't find that default civiCRM created date that shows up on bottom of civiCRM results, what is that field called?

Comment: @BrunoVincent I think you've lost me a bit.  Could you please edit your question to show the screen(s) you're looking at?  And comment on this answer, Stack Exchange won't notify me otherwise.

Comment: Ok Jon G - Megaphone Tech , I fixed the question, it actually evolved over time as I learned! ;)